# Subquery supposedly returns more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DEL_RouteStops_CatalogID]
   ON  [dbo].[RouteStops]
   AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    DECLARE @rowcount int
    DECLARE @rowsexist bit

    SET @rowcount = (SELECT COUNT(a.RouteStopID) FROM RouteStops a, deleted d WHERE a.StopCIXID = d.StopCIXID)


    IF (@rowcount > 0)
    BEGIN
    SET @rowsexist = 'true'

**SUPPOSEDLY THE BELOW LINE RETURNS MORE THAN 1 RESULT?!**  
    IF @rowsexist = 'true'
    BEGIN   

    UPDATE LocationCatalog
    SET NextSubmitDate = (SELECT MIN(a.UD5) FROM RouteStops a, deleted d where a.StopCIXID IN (d.StopCIXID))
    FROM RouteStops a, LocationCatalog b, deleted d
    WHERE b.RouteStopID = d.RouteStopID

    UPDATE LocationCatalog
    SET SubmitDay = (SELECT a.Route FROM RouteStops WHERE UD5 = (SELECT MIN(a.UD5) FROM RouteStops a, deleted d where a.StopCIXID = d.StopCIXID)),
        NextPickDate = (SELECT dateadd(D, a.UD2, b.NextSubmitDate) FROM RouteStops a, deleted d where a.StopCIXID IN (d.StopCIXID)),
        NextDeliveryDate = (SELECT dateadd(D, a.UD3, b.NextSubmitDate) FROM RouteStops a, deleted d where a.StopCIXID IN (d.StopCIXID))
    FROM RouteStops a, LocationCatalog b, deleted d
    WHERE b.RouteStopID = d.RouteStopID

    END

END
END
```

Comment: I don't see the question.

Comment: Not *supposedly*. It does, SQL Server doesn't look at the query and *thinks* it will return more than one row. It executed it and it **actually** returned more than one row. You need to go through the subqueries and figure out which one that does this and fix that.

Comment: Also, you could probably rewrite this to not use subqueries at all.  You'd still need to remove duplicates, though - `RouteStops` is the likely culprit - or results may not be what you want.  However, you haven't given enough information to be able to help you that way.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the subqueries you use to assign `NextPickDate` and `NextDeliveryDate` 
is it possible that these return more than one row ?

these subqueries need checking out:

```
SELECT dateadd(D, a.UD2, b.NextSubmitDate) 
FROM RouteStops a, deleted d where a.StopCIXID IN (d.StopCIXID)

SELECT dateadd(D, a.UD3, b.NextSubmitDate) 
FROM RouteStops a, deleted d where a.StopCIXID IN (d.StopCIXID)
```

you can try using an appropriate aggregate operator to ensure the subquery returns only one row; for example:

```
SELECT min(dateadd(D, a.UD2, b.NextSubmitDate)) 
FROM RouteStops a, deleted d where a.StopCIXID IN (d.StopCIXID)
```